# php regex find symbols in a string

Tags: php, regex

How in a string

```
-1 -2 -3 -4
```

get

```
array(-1, -2, -3, -4)
```

using regex and function

```
preg_match_all
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
/(([-]?\d+))/gmi
```

The result:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-3]   `-1`
MATCH 2
1.  [8-10]  `-2`
MATCH 3
1.  [15-17] `-3`
MATCH 4
1.  [22-24] `-4`
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/bS8xZ1/3)

In PHP usage:

```
  $string = '(-1) * (-2) - (-3) * (-4)';
  $regex = '/(([-]?\d+))/i';

  preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

  print_r($matches[1]);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => -2 [2] => -3 [3] => -4 )
```

Comment: necessary to use only (-1) * (-2) - (-3) * (-4), not (-1) * (-2) + (-3) * (-4) or another